# Can Crontab be used to manage packages if it requires input only some of the time

Tags: bash, input, cron, pip, conda

I essentially have a suite of python packages, binaries, and other programs requiring constant updates and I wanted to see if I could create a crontab entry that would run a BASH script that basically just runs these updates monthly. I have successfully created a crontab entry that calls a shorter test script I wrote for this purpose. The script is not the issue but it is as follows if it helps answer the question, which I doubt.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Program update automator script
#Leveraging crontab to update all my neuroimaging, python, and conda packages monthly without having to do it myself because I forget and am a lazy POS
#Note - Am Using Conda and Pip for package management and not apt-get, which I don't think I have installed because I had read somewhere you can get discrepancies in processes if you have apt-get and one of the other ones both on the system

#Created 12.27.17
#Updated 12.27.17

#Updates Conda itself and cleans unused packages and tarballs out
conda update conda && conda update anaconda && conda clean --packages --tarballs

#Update AFNI binaries
@update.afni.binaries -defaults -do_extras

#Updating important Python libraries
conda update python ipython ipython-notebook matplotlib networkx numpy scipy sphinx traits dateutil nose pydot

#Update Nipype libraries
pip install --upgrade nibabel nipype rdflib nipy dipy pygraphviz graphviz
```

Because I had just run all these commands prior to making this entry, testing it caused it to run without error. The problem is, when I run ONLY SOME of these updates when updates ARE required you get the whole:

> The following packages will be updated: Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Which requires user input.
Is there a way I can automate the process of inputting 'y'?
There are a couple of issues I can see.

1. The most pressing, obviously, is that cron will crash if it gets to a point where it needs input, correct? I have not seen this myself yet but this is what I have read.
2. I am not sure how many times I will ever need to provide input, as it is always variable which commands will have programs that need updating and which will not, so it's not as if I will always need to input 3 'y's' and it's not as if the same commands will need the same input from run to run.

Is this just a bad idea?

My current crontab entry is as follows:

```
0 10 1 * * source /Users/mycomputer/.bash_profile; /bin/sh /Users/mycomputer/Desktop/auto_package_updater.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entries describe commands to be run periodically (or, with `@reboot` at boot time). These commands are interpreted by `/bin/sh` (the POSIX shell, see [sh(1p)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html)...) with a prior substitution of the `%` character.

Notice that these commands are running in a different environment (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)...) than your interactive shell has. Hence, you may need to set your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (and perhaps other environment variables, such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you need it) explicitly in your `auto_package_updater.sh` shell script (instead of `source /Users/mycomputer/.bash_profile` which *smells really bad* ...) .

> is that cron will crash if it gets to a point where it needs input,

No, [cron(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) is a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) -started by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) at boot time- and does not crash (unless you got hit by a bug in `cron` itself, which is very unlikely). It always runs (and if you crash it -which is highly unlikely, you cannot run any `crontab` job afterwards). What could happen is that your particular cron job is blocked ...

> Is there a way I can automate the process of inputting 'y'?

You could consider using [yes(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) (which emits a potentially infinite stream of `y` lines) and [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) its output (see [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)). For example, if `pip install --upgrade nibabel nipype` could want many `y` you might put in your shell script:

```
yes | pip install --upgrade nibabel nipype
```

<sup>(but be cautious! are you so sure you always want that?)</sup>

BTW, I am not sure it is wise to entirely automate the update of your software. How would you handle the failure of these updates, or updates to a buggy version? I would recommend to download automatically, but update manually.... And you probably should avoid updating a Python program while that program is running....

Maybe you just want to write your own updating [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) (to avoid typing repetitive commands) but run that `update_my_python_packages` script yourself, when you *know* it is reasonable to do so.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for 'crash.' I should have said, 'stop.'

If I did something like the following (with the correct paths and sourcing) I know this theoretically would pipe 'y' into the script but would it work for multiple instances of needed to input 'y'?
* * * * * y | myscript.sh

As to updating automatically like this, I wasn't sure it would be good, just easier because I forget which packages are most necessary but it might just not be the best way to go.

Comment: What is stopped is not the `cron` daemon, but your particular and buggy cron job only. Not a big deal.

Comment: Oh wait, so piping yes(1) just REPEATEDLY pipes 'y' until the script terminates? (I.E. * * * * * yes(1) | myscript.sh). Ah that would take care of needing any number of multiple 'y's' if I'm understanding that correctly. Would that kind of repeated input cause any unintended behavior in the job?

Comment: RTFM. `yes` produces an infinite stream of `y` but the right side of the pipe (here `pip install --upgrade nibabel nipype`) will read a finite amount of them.

Comment: I appreciate your point about the buggy software. While the concept I outlined seems theoretically helpful the updater script seems like a better idea given the patches many of these softwares end up requiring. Thank you for your commentary, it was very helpful.